# The Sam I used to know doesn't exist anymore

Tags: articles

Is the use of the article "the" correct in this case? Why?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, because it is a standard use of the [definite article The](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Definite_article) in English.

Adding the article *The* in this case implies that Sam has changed to the point that he has had at least two distinctively different personalities.  Now, figuratively, there are multiple Sams.

Then, in saying *The Sam*, you are referring to the version of that personality that you used to know.